# Is there auto-import functionality for typescript in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any shortcut that will allow me to auto generate my typescript imports? Like hitting ctrl+space next to the type name and having the import declaration placed at the top of the file. If not, what about intellisense for filling out the module reference path so that I wont have to do it manually? I would really love to use vscode but having to do manual imports for typescript is killing me.

Answer (score 2):

There are rumors of making it support tsconfig.json (well, better than rumors). This will allow us to be able to use all files for our references.

Your feature would be to create an auto import of all commonly used 3rd party libs into the typings. Perhaps auto scan the files and create a list of ones to go gather. Wouldn't it be fine to just have a quick way to add several of these using tsd directly from Code (interactively)?

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the reply. What about when importing external modules. Is there any help with that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the plugin called "TypeScript Importer" does exactly what You mean: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pmneo.tsimporter .

> Automatically searches for TypeScript definitions in workspace files and provides all known symbols as completion item to allow code completion.

> [image]

With it You can truly use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to choose what exactly You would like to be imported.

You can find and install it from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> menu or just by pasting `ext install tsimporter` in Quick Open menu opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @M.A.R., eh, I'm not a fan of marking the answer as 'not useful' when it just doesn't meet Your standards for 'perfect answer'... Anyway, is it better right now?

Comment: I was not the downvoter, so can't provide a reason for a downvote I haven't done.

Comment: @M.A.R. ok, sorry that I unjustly accused You then.
Could somebody explain the downvote though?

Answer (score 2):

This has just been released in [version 1.18](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_auto-import-for-javascript-and-typescript).

From the release notes:

## Auto Import for JavaScript and TypeScript

Speed up your coding with auto imports for JavaScript and TypeScript. The suggestion list now includes all exported symbols in the current project. Just start typing:

[image: Global symbols are now shown in the suggestion list]

If you choose one of the suggestion from another file or module, VS Code will automatically add an import for it. In this example, VS Code adds an import for `Hercules` to the top of the file:

[image: After selecting a symbol form a different file, an import is added for it automatically]

Auto imports requires TypeScript 2.6+. You can disable auto imports by setting `"typescript.autoImportSuggestions.enabled": false`.

Answer (score 1):

I know a solution for Visual Studio (not Visual Studio *Code*, I'm using the 2015 Community edition, which is free), but it needs some setup and coding -- however, I find the results to be adequate.

Basically, in Visual Studio, when using the Web-Essentials extension, `.ts` files can be dragged into the active document to automatically generate a relative reference path comment:

```
/// <reference path="lib/foo.ts" />
```

With which of course we might as well wipe it, because it's an `import` statement we need, not a reference comment.

For this reason, I recently wrote the following command snippet for Visual Commander, but it should be easily adaptable to other use casese as well. With Visual Commander, your drag the needed imports into the open document, then run the following macro:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    // Called by Visual Commander extension.
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        TextDocument doc = (TextDocument)(DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument"));
        var p = doc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint();
        string s = p.GetText(doc.EndPoint);

        p.ReplaceText(doc.EndPoint, this.ReplaceReferences(s), (int)vsEPReplaceTextOptions.vsEPReplaceTextKeepMarkers);
    }

    // Converts "reference" syntax to "ES6 import" syntax.
    private string ReplaceReferences(string text)
    {
        string pattern = "\\/\\/\\/ *<reference *path *= *\"([^\"]*)(?:\\.ts)\" *\\/>";

        var regex = new Regex(pattern);
        var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

        return Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "import {} from \"./$1\";");
    }
}
```

When running this snippet, all reference comments in the active document will be replaced with `import` statements. The above example is converted to:

```
import {} from "./lib/foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

The files attributes in the tsconfig.json file allows you to set your reference imports in your whole project. It is supported with Visual Studio Code, but please note that if you're using a specific build chain (such as tsify/browserify) it might not work when compiling your project.

Comment: Hi Frédéric. Thanks for the reply. What about when importing external modules. Is there any help with that?