# Visual Studio Code Automatic Imports

Tags: typescript, angular, visual-studio-code

I'm in the process of making the move from Webstorm to Visual Studio Code.  The Performance in Webstorm is abysmal.

Visual studio code isn't being very helpful about finding the dependencies I need and importing them.  I've been doing it manually so far, but to be honest I'd rather wait 15 seconds for webstorm to find and add my import that have to dig around manually for it.

[image: Screenshot: cannot find import]

I'm using the angular2 seed from @minko-gechev  https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

I have a tsconfig.json in my baseDir that looks like this:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/modules",
    "src"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

and I have another one in my src/client dir that looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

I don't know why there are two.  The angualr seed project uses typescript gulp build tasks so I guess the compilation is different.

What can I do get vscode to be more helpful??

Comment: Give http://alm.tools/ a go 

Comment: :-) experiencing the same at the moment. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yep - I found out EVERYTHING is added via extensions.  Try "auto import" "typescript import assistance" "tsd-recommender" "npm intellisense"

Comment: I tried "auto import" extension and it kinda hangs while indicating it is "scanning".  I am on Windows 10.  Anybody has the same problem?

Comment: @reach4thelasers hey, I too am in the same position as you were trying to find an extensions etc, I've installed the extensions you have specified above, I then copied the code you mentioned in the photo however I still get the red error under PipeTransform it doesn't give me the option to automatically import it, instead I get the error what you display in your photo... did you managed to resolve this?

Comment: Hey @CodeRatchet I posted an answer with a list of my extensions and some more info.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014812/is-there-auto-import-functionality-for-typescript-in-visual-studio-code :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I got this working by installing the various plugins below.

Most of the time things just import by themselves as soon as I type the class name.  Alternatively, a lightbulb appears that you can click on.  Or you can push <kbd>F1</kbd>, and type "import..." and there are various options there too.  I kinda use all of them.  Also <kbd>F1</kbd> Implement for implementing an interface is helpful, but doesn't always work.

#### List of Plugins

- [npm Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.npm-intellisense)
- [ngrx for Angular 2 Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidpiercedev.code-ngrx-snippets)
- [TypeScript Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DSKWRK.vscode-generate-getter-setter)
- [npm](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fknop.vscode-npm)
- [TsTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iBotMedia.tstools)
- [Angular Snippets (Version 9)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.Angular2)
- [Types auto installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jvitor83.types-autoinstaller)
- [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)
- [TypeScript Importer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pmneo.tsimporter)
- [TypeScript Hero](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero)
- [vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)
- [Add Angular Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastianbaar.vscode-add-angular2-files)

Screenshot of Extensions

[image: screenshot of extensions]
<sup>**click for full resolution*</sup>

Comment: did you have to modify any config files? or was it a simple install and enable?

Comment: No I don't think any config modifications are required.  The only thing thats in my settings.json is "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib/" which forces vscode to use the version of typescript in the node_modules rather than the one installed on the system.

Comment: FYI my typescript version from the packages.json is  "typescript": "2.0.3",

Comment: Can you please provide you plugins as a list, since your attached image is no longer visible?

Comment: `TypeScript Importer` works well, also with custom `rootDirs` or mappings using `paths` in `tsconfig.json`. It fixes the broken autoimport of VS Code.

Comment: I installed `TypeScript Importer` and `TypeScript Toolbox`. Both worked for me. +1

Comment: Typescript importer worked for me, thank you!

Comment: @Lion Are you able to make Typescript Importer use tsconfig.json `paths` for newly created files? Tsconfig.json `paths` works for me, but only after adding one import of the file to the project.

Comment: @Lion TypeScript Importer was enough to add imports for package and "built-in"(react/react-native) stuff, but it does not always respect path aliases in tsconfig.json and doesn't work every time, for 1 file it barely worked, for other it worked perfectly aliases included, not sure what's wrong 

Answer (score 99):

2018 now. You don't need any extensions for auto-imports in Javascript (as long as you have `checkjs: true` in your `jsconfig.json` file) and TypeScript.

There are two types of auto imports: the add missing import [quick fix](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_code-action) which shows up as a lightbulb on errors:

[image]

And the [auto import suggestions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports). These show up a suggestion items as you type. Or you can select text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up a list of suggestions. Accepting an auto import suggestion automatically adds the import at the top of the file

[image]

Both should work out of the box with JavaScript and TypeScript. If auto imports still do not work for you, please [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose)

Comment: Yes, auto-imports work great on Mac out of the box regardless of if your project's version of typescript matches with what shipped with VScode, but in other OS's, namely linux, this is not the case, and you must point to the workspace's version of TS as I explained in my answer.

Comment: That is not correct. If what I describe above is not working, it is a bug and you should file a bug report. I am the maintainer of VS Code's JS/TS support and implemented these features

Comment: For anyone else having trouble with auto importing React components, I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66122

Comment: is there any hotkeys for this? I don't want to click the lightbulb every time I want import something `cmd+.` on Mac

Comment: @buncis did you find a shortcut for this ?

Comment: @Tonio `cmd+.` on Mac

Comment: @MattBierner having authored my own autoimport tools for JS/Flow/Atom and planning on switching to Typescript soon, I'm curious: does VSCode base its suggestions solely on export statements, or does it also base them on our own import statements (for example if we `import {foo as bar} from 'foo'`, will it include that in suggestions for `bar` in another file?)

Comment: It uses the exported symbol names

Comment: @MattBierner is this supposed to autoimport Angular components as well? Judging from the screenshot that seems to be what OP meant.

Comment: 2020 the auto-fix variety doesn't seem to work for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: It's not full auto import if you have to navigate to each red underline, hit Ctrl+1, and pick from a list. Eclipse for Java does every import in the file with one keystroke and makes a popup if it can't decide.

Comment: @Noumenon See auto import suggestions

Comment: @MattBierner That's the same number of keystrokes, when you paste or type a bunch of code and have to do one backspace on each red underline, then Ctrl+Space, then pick from the list. I'd call it "assisted import", when compared to fully automated import like Eclipse's single Ctrl+Shift+O command.

Comment: [Single source action that adds all missing imports](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_add-all-missing-imports-source-action)

Comment: @MattBierner Thanks. I used this method in your above link to auto-import `EventEmitter` into an Angular 9 app.  The result I got was that `EventEmitter` was auto-imported from `protractor` file instead of from the correct  `@angular/core`.  I didn't get an error when trying to assign an event handler as an `EventEmitter` in VSCode (_no red line_) so there was no "light bulb" for a quick fix  and no 'auto import suggestions' as I typed.  Is there something I need to do in VSCode _BEFORE_ I right-click and select 'Source Action' in the context menu as shown in your linked solution above?  Thx!

Comment: @Matt Bierner. Thank you for your work on VS Code.  In VS code 1.56.1 it seems`checkjs` is not a permitted property, but `"checkJs": true` works.

Comment: @Matt Bierner don't know how about you, but once you have big enough project auto import just stops working. Suggestions are empty.

Comment: What's strange is that auto-import works out of the box in a plain javascript project while initially typing, but if you accept the import, then delete the import statement, vscode magically no longer has any idea that it's something that can be imported (no quick fix suggestions). The only thing that works for me for initial typing and quick fix after-the-fact is to add the jsconfig with checkJS set to true.

Comment: Shift + alt + "o" on pc organizes imports and removes the ones you don't need (but do not add missing ones, for that you need ctr + "." or ctr + space)

Answer (score 29):

I used [**Auto Import**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) plugin by steoates which is quite easy.

> Automatically finds, parses and provides code actions and code completion for all available imports. Works with Typescript and TSX.

Comment: I can confirm this plugin works well. It even ignores my `index.ts`. By default VS Code wants to import from my `index.ts` file. Great answer!

Comment: Unfortunately did not help me, still can't auto-import from modules in `node_modules` :(

Comment: Adding this extension worked for me.  It correctly auto-imported the `EventEmitter` from  `@angular/core` (_as it was red-lined for the Quick Fix_).  Without that extension, it was importing `EventEmitter` from `protractor` (_which wasn't what I wanted_). I have a question to the MS VSCode maintainer @MattBierner here concerning the different import source.

Comment: Auto Import TypeScript support rocks!

Comment: I just installed it and works fine for me.

Answer (score 28):

In the tsconfig.app.json, a standard Angular 10 app has:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Once I changed the include like to be:

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
```

It worked for me
[image: It worked for me]

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution does work. The trouble was in tsconfig preferences, as it turned out, but not in the IDE.

Comment: I would be better to add your solution in the `tsconfig.editor.json` )) After I made changes in the `tsconfig.app.json` the app build was broken)

Comment: This is what I needed to fix missing imports when referring to node modules in another directory using tsconfig path configuration. ty

Answer (score 17):

##### For Javascript projects:

- Set [`Check JS`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_jsconfig-options) settings flag works for me.
- No need to create a `jsconfig.json` in project

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!
Now everything is working as it should!

Comment: I set the Check JS flag, reloaded VS window - nothing happed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

If anyone has run into this issue recently, I found I had to add a setting to use my workspace's version of typescript for the auto-imports to work. To do this, add this line to your *workspace* settings:

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Then, with a typescript file open in vscode, click the **typescript version number** in the lower right-hand corner. When the options at the top appear, choose "use workspace version", then **reload vscode**.

Now auto-imports should work.

Comment: This is not necessary. Auto imports work using VS Code's bundled version of typescript

Comment: @MattBierner in my case, it was necessary as I was using VScode on linux (CentOS). Auto-imports did not work until I pointed to the workspace installation of Typescript, which was quite a bit older than what ships with VScode

Comment: This is not good advice in almost all cases. If you don't see auto imports working with the bundled version of typescript, please file a bug report: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=bug_report.md

Comment: @MattBierner in the context of a Q&A site it is good advice. When auto-imports do not work, knowing it is a bug does not solve their problem. We don't want to wait for a bug fix for this edge case and I'm not going to file yet another bug in a repo that has tens of thousands of issues. Lastly I'd just like to point out that [this is the advice that is prescribed on the VScode website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-the-workspace-version-of-typescript)

Comment: Look: I wrote the documentation you are linking to and implemented this feature in VS Code. Your advice is misguided in the context of this question and will cause unnecessary confusion. It may work for you but it is not the proper solution. As I said before, we always expect auto imports to work. If they do not work using the bundled version of VS Code, please report an issue against VS Code so that we can fix it. We will let you know if you should downgrade as a temporary workaround

Comment: Matt, it is not important to those who are suffering from this issue whether their solution is "proper" or not. The fact is, this solution fixed the problem for me and others I'm working with. I don't expect it to fix the problem for everyone, but I wanted to leave it here in case it helps someone. And honestly - we are talking about using the version of TS that is supported in a project, seems like we should be doing that anyway no?

Comment: Also, I'm seeing an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61660) in which you suggested upgrading TS for your workspace - please understand that in many projects that is not possible, especially Angular where only up to a certain version of TS is supported

Comment: The original question was "Can VS Code provide auto imports like webstorm?" The answer is: yes it can. There are many unique cases where auto imports may still not work as expected due configuration issues or bugs like the one you may be hitting, but I do not think these should posted as answers here as they are often project specific and will get out date. We also want people reporting issues instead of trying to work around them

Comment: I don't want to keep this silly discussion going on forever, but, put yourself in my shoes. Should I wait for maintainers to get around to fixing my issue (that may only exist on Linux), when they have 4K open issues, or use a very benign, simple, harmless and quick fix to make it work now?

Comment: So when auto imports DON'T work, and I'm using a bunch of extensions, how do I know to file a bug report with VS Code instead of one of the extensions?

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue with detecting missing imports

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same problem: Visual Studio Code (v. 1.45.1) not adding imports automatically for one of my typescript projects. In my case, the problem was project specific and no extensions had to be added to VS Code.

Fix:

1. Add `"importHelpers": true` to the compileOptions section of the tsconfig.json file.
2. Restart VS Code.

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
...
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

VS Code supports this out of the box now, but the feature sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, it seems. As far as I could find out, VS Code has to load data needed for auto imports, which happens more or less like this:

- Load data for all exports from your local files
- Load data for all exports from node_modules/@types
- Load data for all exports from node_modules/{packageName} only if any of your local files is importing them

This is better described in this comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31763#issuecomment-537226190.

Due to bugs either in VS Code or in specific packages' type declarations, the last two points don't always work. That was my case, I couldn't see react-bootstrap auto imports in a plain Create-React-App. What finally fixed it was manually copying the package folder from node_modules to node_modules/@types and leaving there only the type declaration files, e.g. Button.d.ts. This is not great because if you ever delete node_modules folder it will stop working again. But I prefer this from always having to manually type imports.
This was my last resort after trying and failing with these methods:

- Update VS Code (v. 1.45.1)
- Install types for your package, e.g. `npm install --save @types/react-bootstrap`
- Add jsconfig.json file and play with the settings as other people suggested
- Try out all the plugins for automatic imports

Answer (score 2):

Fill the `include` property in the first level of the JSON-object in the `tsconfig.editor.json` like here:

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*.ts"
]
```

It works for me well.

Also you can add another Typescript file extensions if it's needed, like here:

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*.ts",
  "src/**/*.spec.ts",
  "src/**/*.d.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add "typeRoots" attribute in tsconfig.json:

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/@angular",
      "node_modules/@angular/common/http"
    ]
```

You may add any other necessary path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular, check that the `tsconfig.json` does not contain errors. (in the problems terminal)

For some reason I doubled these lines, and it didn't work for me

```json
{
  "module": "esnext",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem on Typescript Version 3.8.3.

Intellisense is the best thing we could have but for me, the auto-import feature doesn't seem to work either. I've tried installing an extension even though auto-import didn't work. I've rechecked all the settings related to extensions. Finally, the auto-import feature started working when I clear the cache, from

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache

& reload the VSCode

Note: AppData can only be visible in username if you select, Show (Hidden Items) from (View) Menu.

In some cases, we may end up thinking there is an import related error, while in actuality, unknowingly we might be coding using deprecated features or APIs in angular.

For example: if you're trying to code something like this

constructor (http: Http) {

//...}

Where Http is already deprecated and replaced with HttpClient in the newer version, so we may end up thinking an error related to this might be related to the auto-import error. For more information, you can refer [Deprecated APIs and Features](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript Importer does do the job for me

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pmneo.tsimporter

It automatically searches for typescript definitions inside your workspace and when you press enter it'll import it.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript projects like ReactJs or React-Native just follow theses steps.

1. First remove all the auto import plugins becuase vc code automatically contains this feature.
2. Add a new file in the root of the project called jsconfig.json
3. Now add this code:

   ```
   {
      "exclude": ["node_modules"]
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

There is a [Visual Studio Code issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/818) you can track and thumbs up for this feature. There was also a [User Voice issue](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/13344849-auto-imports-in-typescript), but I believe they moved voting to GitHub issues.

It seems they want auto import functionality in TypeScript, so it can be reused. [TypeScript auto import issue to track and thumbs up here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7849).

Answer (score -1):

> I am using 'ImportJS' plugin by Devin Abbott for auto import and you can
> install this using below code
>
> `npm install --global import-js`

Answer (score -1):

VScode 1.57 (May 2021) reminds us of the (now) *native* auto import feature, and... improves it:

> ### Completions in import statements
>
> Auto import in JavaScript and TypeScript automatically add imports when you accept a suggestion.
>
> With VS Code 1.57, they now also work when writing an import statement itself:
>
> [image: Auto imports in an import statement -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/3e7e9293475f03a5263084d659f9dea6bf06dcc4/release-notes/images/1_57/ts-import.gif]
>
> This can be a time saver if you ever need to manually add an import.