# Visual Studio Code - Angular 2 auto import extension

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Just finished setting up visual studio code for learning Angular 2.

I've currently installed the following extension for TypeScript:

1. TSLint

Along with a new theme etc, I'm curious to find out if an extension exists for the following scenario:

Say I'm creating a form within Angular 2, inside this form I would be using a FormControl if I don't manually import FormControl from @angular2/forms then of course it wouldn't work, has an extension been created whereby if I type FormControl it'll alert me and say you need to import X from X ?

Reason I ask this is because it'll help me greatly to learn where things live and so forth.

*Update*

So spent some time today to carry on my search to find the relevant extensions I need to auto import symbols from other files and modules automatically, I came across this [Visual Studio automatic import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210604/visual-studio-code-automatic-imports) however the extensions the OP specified don't seem to work for all symbols.  In the image the OP uploaded I copied the code, when I wrote `Pipe` it prompted me to import `Pipe` from `@angular/core` however when typing `PipeTransform` it didn't give me the import option, instead it just said `Cannot find name PipeTransform`

Or if anyone who uses Visual Studio Code with Angular 2 could outline what extensions they use that would also be beneficial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [Typescript Hero](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero). It does a great job of importing custom parts of your application and helps you easily resolve situations where there is a name conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can take a look at some of the suggestions here: [Visual Studio Code Automatic Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210604/visual-studio-code-automatic-imports). Specifically [Typescript toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DSKWRK.vscode-generate-getter-setter) which can handle some of the built in modules.