# Broken autoimport in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code for Angular 2+ development.

After a while, the autoimport for classes and dependencies stopped working partially. I don't know what I have exactly done but before that everything worked fine.
Now it doesn't find all available exported classes, for example, Angular's or mine. A concrete example: if I try to import *Router*, it should add:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

But now I don't get this option:
[image: Example of importing Router.]

I reinstalled VSCode and disabled all plugins but the issue still persists.

I Googled, I found possible solutions for example this pages:

- [Visual Studio Code Automatic Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210604/visual-studio-code-automatic-imports/39906470)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28417

But none of them solved my problem as doesn't match exactly to my problem.

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.22.1. (But the issue started with a previous version.) It runs on Windows 10.

I can type manually the import and it's working correctly. But it's a drop in productivity. Where should I search the cause? Or maybe it can be an Angular related issue more than an IDE one?

It works fine on my other computer and works fine for my colleagues.

Comment: Is this on a PC, MAC, or LINUX?  If it is on Windows, you can try uninstalling again.  But, this time I would recommend using- https://geekuninstaller.com/ and runs as a stand-alone software (does not need to be installed to run).

Comment: Yes, it is on Windows. I already tried to reinstall it. I update the description.

Comment: @Leptonator I will give a try to your suggestions. However first I would like to try a softer solution.

Comment: Is there any alternative plugin for Auto Import?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `checkjs: true` to your `jsconfig.json` file (in your project root directory) should enable automatic imports now *without* the need for any separate extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you need is done with the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Or by updating File->Preferences->Settings->Text Editor:

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  },
```