# VSCode javascript auto import working, but not with auto-fix

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

If i start typing, i get the option to auto import from files. However, when i click on the yellow lightbulb and look at auto-fix options, the auto import is missing.

What could be interfering if this should work out of the box, and where should i look to enable this feature?

[image]

Comment: following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015835/4062197 auto complete works automatically for both `javascript` and `typescript`.. are you sure that the libarary which `mergeObjects` came from is properly declared in your project? (for instance: in `node.js` you should include it as part of your `package.json` file)

Comment: Yeah i saw it there, and i've always seen this feature, but im in a new code base. `mergeObjects` should come from `mergeObjects.js` somewhere in my project, not node.js though. Auto imports fine with a relative path when i start typing.