# Angular 10: Cannot find name when trying to import module

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I created a new Angular project and a new module inside that project using the CLI. If I try to import the newly created module in `app.module.ts` the Intellisense doesn't work and it can't find the module to auto-import it. I didn't change anything inside the `tsconfig.json` files.

- Angular CLI: 10.0.4
- Node: 12.16.3
- Angular: 10.0.5
- Typescript: 3.9.7
- VS Code: 1.47.3

Any idea what could cause it?

**EDIT:** A manual import works fine, but I'm asking about the auto-import functionality.

[image]

[image]

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

Comment: have you tried import {TestModule} from './test/test.module'; ?

Comment: @pbachman Yes, a manual import is ok and the class is recognized. But auto-import doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210604/visual-studio-code-automatic-imports ?

Comment: @pbachman It seems like the Auto Import extension is working fine, excepting the fact that it imports the module at the top of the file. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport

Comment: @pbachman The problem is that VS Code has the auto-import feature built in. I see no reason to use the extension and I would like to find the root cause of the problem, if there is any. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the source of the problem in the `tsconfig.json` inside the project's root folder.

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
]
}
```

If you just change it to this

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

VS Code auto-import starts working

As I understand it the main problem is "files": [], typescript stops seeing all files that are not included in the project.

[github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39632](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39632)
[https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/876](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/876#issuecomment-667397073)
People offer the same solution

Comment: Update: the fix is not needed anymore for Angular 10.1.3

Answer (score -1):

Try exporting child components inside Testmodule like this

```
 @NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [CommonModule],
      exports: [components]
    })
export class TestModule { }
```

Comment: There is no component in the module, so your answer is not applicable :)