# Cypress: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress/types/lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lodash, cypress

I am running my first test in Cypress from VS IDE and Cypress was working while until I encountered the error below without having changed or updated anything..

My Cypress (7.0.0) installed via NPM command using Node.js 14.16.1 is encountering "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress/types/lodash" error message when executing my tests.

I have tried to remove all loadash files from the project and executing the code but the error remains unchanged.

Can someone please tell me how I can diagnose or fix this issue!!

---

### **Error Message:**

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/integration/myTests/helloWorld.test.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress/types/lodash' in 'C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\cypress\integration\myTests'
resolve 'cypress/types/lodash' in 'C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\cypress\integration\myTests'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\package.json (relative path: ./cypress/integration/myTests)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\cypress\integration\myTests\node_modules]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\cypress\integration\node_modules]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\cypress\node_modules]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\node_modules]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\node_modules]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\node_modules]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\node_modules]
[C:\Users\.....\node_modules]
[C:\Users\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash.js]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash.json]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash.jsx]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash.mjs]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash.coffee]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash\index]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash\index.js]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash\index.json]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash\index.jsx]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash\index.mjs]
[C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\Tools\Cypress\Software\node_modules\cypress\types\lodash\index.coffee]
 @ ./cypress/integration/myTests/helloWorld.test.js 6:4-35
 
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:172:23)
    at C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:99:9
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Watching._done (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:98:28)
    at C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:73:19
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:499:39)
    at C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:54:20
    at C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:482:27
    at C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at done (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
```

Comment: please share your test file and package.json file

Comment: Thanks @mosaad, I found the issue was that a new line of code was added to my test file, not sure how it got there but removing it fixed the issue. "const { values } = require("cypress/types/lodash")"

Comment: @user3537901 vscode sneakily added something similar to this for me and caused the same issue

Answer (score 10):

Be aware in my js file the following was added automatically;

```
const { contains } = require("cypress/types/jquery");
```

deleting this line of code, problem solved

Comment: Please format the text a little, so its more readable for other users.

Answer (score 4):

Remove this line from your code and compile again.

```js
const { eq } = require("cypress/types/lodash");
```

Answer (score 3):

It says that your file ./cypress/integration/myTests/helloWorld.test.js is not found on this path. Check if file really exist on this path or does this path is really accessible by accessing it in visual studio code.

Just try this. Type in command line in your project directory

```
npm install
```

and then again run, it will resolve the issue,hopefully

Comment: Thanks Abdullah!!!, it appeared that a new line of code was introduced to my test file which was causing the test to fail. Not sure how this line was added to the code but removing this worked for me!! "const { values } = require("cypress/types/lodash")"

Comment: it just happened to me too. Typed _.find_ and vscode imported `import { find } from "cypress/types/lodash";`

Answer (score 0):

Removed following line of code helps me run the script:

```
const { get } = require("cypress/types/lodash");
```

Answer (score 0):

removing this line fixed my issue , this was added automatically

```js
import { sum } from 'cypress/types/lodash'
```

Answer (score -1):

#### TL;DR

Deleting the first `import module` line of your test js code, problem solved.

**As others stated here with a more general answer**

VSCode, maybe other editors as well, adds automatic code to your js test file:

```
const { contains } = require("cypress/types/jquery"); // the prop can vary
```

or

```
import { add } from "cypress/types/jquery" // the prop can vary
```

VSCode has automatic code completion that when you e.g. type `add` the import line above gets added and you wonder why.

So it depends whether you use `ESM` or `CommonJS`, one of the two lines above can be added and you have to delete the line.

More info in a question on Stack:

[Visual Studio Code Automatic Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38210604/1705829)

For Mac, imports seem to work per default as read in this comment:

[Visual Studio Code Automatic Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210604/visual-studio-code-automatic-imports#comment92971697_53015835)