# Was [import { convertTypeAcquisitionFromJson } from "typescript";] automatically inserted?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Having fun with an old AngularJS app that uses some Typescript and the ng1-template (1.0.0).

Today, the "state" routing stopped working for one particular page.

Finally, I noticed the "states" array in angularjs routing was not getting populated with the page's selector name and so was throwing an error when the app tried to navigate there with:

```
this.$state.go(pageSelectorName);
```

The culprit was this line at the top of the @Page file:

```
import { convertTypeAcquisitionFromJson } from "typescript";
```

But I don't recall putting the line there. It appears nowhere else in the code.

Would something have inserted the line automatically or am I brain-dead?

Comment: Don't you have version control?

Comment: Yeah, but the change happened in my working version alone. No others got it. I'm sure it must have been something I did, I just can't figure what it might have been. I'm afraid I haven't been doing frequent commits. TFS, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio Code?

VSCode and some other IDEs will [generously auto-import completions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015835/1426891) if you select them from a dropdown. If you intend to call `convert` and type `conv`, then `convertTypeAcquisitionFromJson` might appear in the dropdown; if you select it, such as by clicking the entry or using the arrow keys and Enter, the IDE will add the import. The added import will stay, even if you catch your mistake and change `convertTypeAcquisitionFromJson` back to `convert`.

This might be very easy to do if you are trying to use the arrow keys to navigate through source code and don't see the autocompletion dropdown: You'd change the selection rather than moving the cursor, and after hitting Enter, you'd go back to moving the cursor as expected.

As Evert mentions in the comments, you may be able to determine whether you added this—or when you or someone else added it—if you're using a version control system.